# Is [refactor-my-code] a meta-tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, meta-tags

The [refactor-my-code](/questions/tagged/refactor-my-code) tag currently has 149 questions, 53 of which are also tagged [refactoring](/questions/tagged/refactoring). It seems like it's either a meta-tag (as it [describes the author's motivation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info)) or a potential synonym to [refactoring](/questions/tagged/refactoring) or [code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review). Am I mistaken? Are there legitimate uses for this tag?

Comment: Solution is to migrate all these questions to codereview.se

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - only if Code Review want them :)

Answer (score 6):

I vote no, this tag should not exist. It has no tag wiki, and as you said, it doesn't describe the content of the question, it it what the author is asking for. Besides, it's borderline off-topic, sounds like those questions belong on code review...

Comment: Agreed. There's a site for those questions now.